# Why does event[1] return undefined but console.log(event) seems to return an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onkeydown

The console.log return this which looks like and array : keyup charCode=0, keyCode=18
But I tried event[1] to get the keycode but it's undefined, how do I extract the keycode from this ?

```
function processKeyDown(event)
{
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Please no jquery only pure js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because event is an object, not an indexed based array. use `event.keyCode` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use **event.keyCode** to access the key that was pressed.